# Updating SQL Table with Java

Tags: java, sql

I am developing an application that can update my database... However, I can't get my Java method working correctly. It gives me the following error: `Must declare the scalar variable "@P0WHERE".` Any suggestions?

The method I am using:

```
public void updateTable() throws SQLException
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Update the following:\n" + this);
            this.getReservationInfo(input);

            DataConnection connection = new DataConnection();

            String query = "UPDATE " + TableName;
            query += "Set Name = ?";
            query += "WHERE Person_ID = " + id;

            connection.updateData(query, person_name);
            connection.closeConnection();
        }
```

Comment: Add spaces before 'SET' and 'WHERE'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add spaces before 'SET' and 'WHERE', otherwise it will not work.

```
String query = "UPDATE " + TableName;
        query += " SET Name = ?";
        query += " , Age = ?";
        query += " , Col1 = ?"; //And other cols 
        query += " WHERE Person_ID = " + id;
```

**EDIT:** Changed query to update multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks this works... However, how would I do this for multiple columns. i.e query += " SET Name = ?, Age =?"; I tried this and it doesn't work. Any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

I think so. You seem to be missing spaces. After the `TableName` and after the `?`.

```
String query = "UPDATE " + TableName;
query += " Set Name = ?"; // tableSet not good, and
                           // ?WHERE is not valid add spaces.
query += " WHERE Person_ID = " + id;
```

Comment: Thanks this works... However, how would I do this for multiple columns. i.e query += " SET Name = ?, Age =?"; I tried this and it doesn't work. Any ideas?